# Mikrotik Firewall rule to drop everything

Tags: firewall, mikrotik

I would like to make rules that will allow traffic only from certain mac addresses, and drop everything else. Do you have any ideas? I have tried `/ip firewall filter add action=drop chain=forward` But it did not work.

Comment: What rules do you have _above_ this rule? Have you checked `/ip firewall filter print where chain=forward`?

Comment: `Flags: X - disabled, I - invalid, D - dynamic 
 0  D ;;; special dummy rule to show fasttrack counters
      chain=forward action=passthrough 

 1    ;;; TEst pc
      chain=forward action=accept src-mac-address=A4:4C:C8:6A:F2:F5 log=no 
      log-prefix="" 

 2    ;;; Drop all Traffic
      chain=forward action=drop log=no log-prefix="" `. The second rule (1) is my test pc for mac filtering.

Comment: @AlbertValaKondor Please don’t put additional information in comments. Instead, [update your question](https://superuser.com/posts/1735854/edit). You can properly format it there, too.

Answer (score 0):

Seems you're looking at the wrong tool. The IP firewall does (by default) not do anything based on MAC addresses - or any filtering at all if source and target are in the same subnet, as routing does not apply in this case. If you want to set up such rules, you need to use the [Bridge Filter](https://wiki.mikrotik.com/wiki/Manual:Interface/Bridge#Bridge_Firewall) feature of RouterOS. Be aware that Layer2/Bridge Filters require quite a bit of processing power.